# bash_completion

Tags: bash

I have a simple script, which creates a symlink `IP_address` -> `config_file` (used for pxe boot). My script is called like this:

```
lnpxe CONFIG HOSTNAME
```

where `CONFIG` is one of my config files stored in `/home/tftp/config/` and `HOSTNAME` is any hostname. Now, I am trying to set up bash_completion for my script. When I type `lnpxe` and then press `TAB`, I would like to have my config files in `/home/tftp/config/` "suggested" to me and autocompleted. Similarly, for the second argument, I would like to have suggestions of available hosts from my `/etc/hosts` file (similar as ping or ssh do)

Here is my `/etc/bash_completion.d/lnpxe` file which does NOT work as I would like to:

```
_lnpxe()
{
    local cur prev
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    _filedir

}
complete -F _lnpxe -o filenames lnpxe
```

Could somebody please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_lnpxe()
{
    HOSTFILE=/etc/hosts
    local word
    COMPREPLY=()
    if [ 1 -eq "$COMP_CWORD" ]; then
      pushd /home/tftp/config &>/dev/null || return 1
      word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f "$word"))
      popd &>/dev/null
    fi
    if [ 2 -eq "$COMP_CWORD" ]; then
      word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -A hostname "$word"))
    fi

}
complete -F _lnpxe lnpxe
```

Comment: thanks, but that does not work

Comment: @user1968963 Strange; it does here (with a different path though but that should not matter). Please run `compgen -f /home/tftp/config/` and `HOSTFILE=/etc/hosts; compgen -A hostname`. What are the outputs? You may rather add them to your question than put them in a comment.

Comment: it works when I add the following at the end: `complete -F _lnpxe lnpxe`

Comment: the only problem is, the first argument autocompletion doeas not suggest the config file, but the whole absolute path to thee config file, i.e. `/home/tftp/config/`. Would you know how to change that ? My script expects relative path (only the filename), and not the absolute path

Comment: @user1968963 You already hat `complete -F _lnpxe -o filenames lnpxe` in your question thus I just corrected the function. I changed to relative paths and edited the answer.

Comment: Works great. That's fantastic. Thanks a lot for your help.